# Why is this Rspec test returning "email already taken"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, factory-bot

This is my spec file, when adding test for context "not as singable updates user balance" I get the error below.

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe Sale do 

  context 'after_commit' do

    context 'assignable' do 
      sale = FactoryGirl.create(:sale, earned_cents: 10, assignable: true)
      after { sale.run_callbacks(:commit) }

      it 'updates user balance' do
        sale.user.balance.should == sale.earned
      end
    end

    context 'not assignable' do 
      sale = FactoryGirl.create(:sale, earned_cents: 10, assignable: false)
      after { sale.run_callbacks(:commit) }

      it 'does not updates user balance' do
        sale.user.balance.should_not == sale.earned
      end
    end

  end 
end
```

And the factories

```
require 'faker'

FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :user do
    email Faker::Internet.email
    password "mypassword"
  end

FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :sale do
    earned_cents 5
    user
  end
end
```

On `/spec/spec_helper.rb` I also had this

```
require 'database_cleaner'
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.before(:suite) do
    DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :transaction
    DatabaseCleaner.clean_with(:truncation)
  end

  config.before(:each) do
    DatabaseCleaner.start
  end

  config.after(:each) do
    DatabaseCleaner.clean
  end
end
```

And this is the error I'm getting.

`` `save!': Validation failed: Email has already been taken (ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid) ``

I guess its related to the `user` reference inside `Sale` Factory, but I have no idea why it is not generating a new user for the second test or deleting it from the database. Any idea?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In your User factory, try this instead:

```
factory :user do
  email { Faker::Internet.email }
  password "mypassword"
end
```

### Why you Must Enclose In Curly Brackets: to Avoid Caching Values

> The `factory(:user)` block is run
>   when defining the factory, and not every time a record is created. So
>   if `Factory::Internet.email` evaluated to `foo@bar.com` the first time,
>   then the factory would attempt to create all subsequent users with
>   that very same email!) (as per @kristinalim, Edited for grammar)

Comment: Yes. The `factory(:user)` block is run when defining the factory, and not every time a record is created. So if `Factory::Internet.email` evaluated to "foo@bar.com" the first time, doing `email Faker::Internet.email` would be like doing `email 'foo@bar.com'`.

Comment: The braces, forming a block, are what enables this email-generating method to be re-run multiple times in this situation.

Comment: Thanks to both @ kristinalim and @schwabsauce for explaining why this anwser is right ;)